# Add sub text to viewport

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I would like to add sub text (a `textGrob`) to a `grid` `Viewport` -- is this possible?

I have figured out how to add sub text to a single chart:

```
require(ggplot2) 
require(gridExtra)

# make the data
timeSeries <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2012-01-01"), by = "mon"), 
                     value = 1:133 + rnorm(133, 0, 10)
                     )


# make the ggplots
gpLine <- ggplot(timeSeries, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
                geom_line()

gpBar <- ggplot(timeSeries, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
                geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

# ggplot + subtext
grid.arrange(gpBar, sub = textGrob("why is this at the bottom?"))
```

... And i can stick the two charts together using a `grid` `Viewport`

```
# two plots, one view
vplayout <- function(x,y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)

pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(3,1)))
print(gpLine, vp = vplayout(1:2, 1))
print(gpBar, vp = vplayout(3, 1))
```

... but i cannot figure out how to add text to the bottom of the resulting viewport.

`Grid` is *so* complete, i'm sure there **must be** a way, but it's hidden to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close:

```
popViewport() # brings you to the top viewport for the whole plotting area
grid.text("Hello Vicar", x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.25, "npc"))
```

After all your commands above.

Comment: +1, thanks -- the text is now mid plot.  I might be being totally daft, but how do i get it to go to the bottom, as `grid.arrange` does with the `sub` call?

Comment: Just adjust the x and y values.  x = y = 0.5 is dead center in the whole plotting region.

Comment: upViewport is generally better than pop

Comment: thanks very much, accepted. At this point i am using +labs(x = "") to make a blank row at the bottom to put the text grob -- is this the _best_ way?

Comment: That depends: are you going to do this a lot, do you need to automate it?  I think the more formal way to do it would be to push viewports as needed.  First, a viewport that is the whole plotting area, then a viewport that is 90% of the height of the first one, with the extra space at the bottom.  Do your vplayout plotting in this second viewport, the move up and plot in the extra 10% space.  If you do `vignette("grid")` you'll get a document that will get you started.  There are several very nice vignettes in grid.

Comment: I'd add that your +labs() method will only work with ggplot2, which precalculates all the space needed for your plot before plotting.  ggplot2 uses grid graphics, but it is possible to use the underlying grid graphics commands to draw things w/o ggplot2.  Have fun.

Comment: @ricardo i'm confused: if all along you wanted the text at the bottom, what was wrong with grid.arrange() and the sub argument?

Comment: @baptiste my understanding of my options is patchy -- my learning has been very problem-solving specific.  My intention is to have a page with a line chart taking up 2/3rds, a bar chart 1/3rd, and a text marker at the bottom. [This] (http://ricardianambivalence.com/2013/05/03/house-prices-slow/) is the finished product.  and yes, i will automate it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing something, as I would simply do the following,

```
grid.arrange(gpLine, gpBar, heights = c(2/3, 1/3), 
     bottom = textGrob("this is my signature", x=1, hjust=1, vjust=0))
```

[image]

*Edit (23/07/2015)*: from v>=2.0.0 of gridExtra, the argument has been changed from `sub` to `bottom` for consistency

Comment: thanks for your edit about `sub` being changed to `bottom`. was banging my head against the wall trying to follow other solutions that recommended `sub`.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of ggplot2, use of `gridExtra::grid.arrange` is not necessary:

```
p <- ggplot(...) + labs(caption = 'text at the bottom')
```

does the trick.